# How does Application Insights' Provider load?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am using Application Insights for a Web Service in Azure, and I have configured it using the "Application Insights" panel under "Settings".

Even though I haven't added any code specifically to use "OpenTelemetry" or "Application Insights SDK", it still somehow knows to use the Application Insights connection string and send log data there.

The only theory I have is that it is using `EventSource` as the logging provider, but some other process is picking up the logging data and sending it to Application Insights.

How does it actually work without any code being added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "magic" there! WebApps has the concept of Extensions, and Application Insights is one such extensions, pre-installed in every AppService instances. When the portal setting is enabled, all it does underneath is set some AppSettings, triggering/activating the extensions. The Application Insights extension itself leverages facility provided by the language/runtime to inject things to a pre-compiled. For .NET, "startup hooks" - https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/host-startup-hook.md and related techniques are used.
Java uses bytecode instrumentation. Some versions of .NET extensions uses a different technique.

Comment: Yes, this was the information I was after.

Answer (score 1):

When you enable application insights as below:

[image]

Then:

[image]

Or it can be enabled while creating the service:

[image]

Then by default the settings(connection string/instrumentation key) related to application insights are created automatically like below after enabling:

[image]

- Because of this it will automatically send logs of the app service to Application insights service.
- If there is no logging in your code or you haven't used any sdk, the logs of code will not be logged but the other logs of the app service will be logged.
- Then it means it is connected to application insights resources and it sends the logs automatically to that application insights resource. If you are using locally the app, SDK's then you need app insights connection string to be given.

Comment: Ok, I understand that the application has the instrumentation key and the connection string to App Insights, but how it is sending it to Application Insights without a library/SDK installed in the project?  I can understand if I had OpenTelemetry or App Insights SDK installed, but I have no such library in my project.   What magic is occurring?

Comment: It is the internal functionality of the Application insights in Portal. If it is enabled, it will send logs to app insights.

Comment: If you were to add OpenTelemetry to the project and use that to configure the connection string via code, in addition to having the Azure configuration setup through Portal, would that end up logging the same statements twice?

Comment: No that wont happen like that, Open telemetry logs will be logged if it is provided in code.